# How to properly apply Angularjs ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm just a beginner in angularjs, and I'm creating an app, I already made the output correctly  but I want to achieve it without using jQuery, I want to do it using angularjs way using **"ng-repeat"**.

The following code is what's inside my controller:

```
.controller('SomeListCtrl',function(SomeFromService, $scope, $stateParams, $http){

var encodedString = 'action=' + 
        encodeURIComponent("getSomething") +
        '&count=' +
        encodeURIComponent("10") + 
        '&page=' +
        encodeURIComponent("1");

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://service.something/site.aspx',
    data: encodedString,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
.success(function(data){
    $scope.myData = data;
})
.error(function(data, status){
    console.log(status);
})
})
```

And this is in my html where I need to pass it:

```
<ion-view view-title="Latest News">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="data as myData" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/myLink/{{data.id}}">
        <img ng-src="http://the-v.net{{data.ImageLink}}">
        <h2>{{data.localTitle}}</h2>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

P.S. The data that the ajax call returns is json. which is constructed this way

```
[{
"id": "5f6e8bac-197f-4ae3-8535-6d892a101d17",
"localTitle": "Public"
}]
```

Comment: This is *entirely* the wrong approach.  You should avoid storing HTML in variables when using angular whenever possible, and instead allow angular to manage your DOM.

Comment: yes that's why I made the question on how to do it in angular js way :)

Comment: I **highly** recommend taking a read through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: I already did even https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat it's just that I'm finding it hard to understand it so maybe I need others opinion since I can't revive other people's post

Comment: What's the new error you're getting?

Comment: Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got 'data as myData'.

Comment: try this `ng-repeat="data in myData"` NOT `ng-repeat="data as myData"`

Comment: WOW!! I got it! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS controllers aims not to use/create HTML elements directly in their code. You use the view/HTML to render the values returned by the AJAX response.

Controller

```
... 
$scope.values = [];

...
.success(function (response,status, headers, config){
    // put the response values in a scope object
    $scope.values = response;
})
...
```

View

```
<!-- render the values using ng-repeat -->
<div ng-repeat="value in values">
    {{value.localTitle}}
</div>
```

References

- [Angular ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)
- [track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

Comment: yes that's why I want to change this in angularjs way.. i'll try this one out first THANKS!

Comment: hey it became a lot more confusing after your edit -_-

Comment: now I got more questions -_-, what is the $index for? and what if the localTitle will be more than 1.

Comment: @JCBorlagdan the tracking is just for duplicate entities in the response. the '$index' is angular way of counting which element is now in the loop (e.g. index 0 for the 1st element, 1 for the 2nd)

Comment: You can disregard the 'track by' for now. I'll revert it to the simpler one

Comment: will this automatically increment on its own up to the last data of the json data?

Comment: @JCBorlagdan yes, it does. it's part of angular ng-repeat

Comment: hmm.. I edited the question.. I did it that way but i'm getting an error.. did i apply it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

just declare your json data in controller with scope then use it on your view

controller.js

```
$scope.myObj = 'http response here';
```

view.html

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="data as myObj"> 
     <td>{{data.localTitle}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll try this one out

Comment: I edited the question.. but i'm getting an error, i applied your answer to my code.. but i don't know if i did something wrong or is it your code?

Comment: aahh.. it should be ng-repeat="data in myObj" but so many thanks for the help!